# Criteria for reasonable comparisons of measures for comparing two networks

Tags: graph-theory, network, research

I am comparing the network measures of two different networks. Most of the comparisons I perform are on the line of Robustness Analysis, Core-Periphery Analysis, K-Core Decomposition and Centrality Analysis.

Because the networks come from a real-world setting, the number of nodes and edges in the two networks differ by a lot.But I am getting interesting insights from my network data, despite the difference in the size of the networks.

Will the comparative study still make sense under the scenario of the different magnitude of network sizes being studied. The line of analysis (Robustness, Core-Periphery, K-Core Decomposition and Centrality Analysis ) aren't dependent upon the size of the network, as far as I learnt. Would I need to consider other network measures other than nodes and edge count, when I am subjecting any two networks under comparative tests?